# How to hide CKEditor widget content from source mode

Tags: javascript, widget, ckeditor, mathjax, ckeditor4.x

I'm developing a new Widget for CKEditor 4 and some of its content is generated dynamically by a tool that parses CKEditor content window.

At first, the widget is simply a `<span class="my-widget"></span>` but then some content will be added on the fly.

When switching to CKEditor's `source` mode, then all the content inside `span` is visible and it gets really messy. Moreover, I don't want to save all that content in database but only the outer `<span class="my-widget"></span>`

I'm pretty sure this is feasible because this is how CKEditor's [MathJax plugin](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/mathjax) works: when inserting a formula using TeX syntax, the plugin generates a `<span class="math-tex">[formula here]</span>`. Then, Mathjax runs and typesets the formula, producing the nice-looking LaTeX-like formula in CKEditor. However, when inspecting the code, it only shows the outer `<span class="math-tex">[formula here]</span>`.

I inspected their source code and I saw they were using an `iframe` inside the widget.

Can someone explain to me how it works and the way to do it without using an `iframe` if possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually achieved the desired result using the [downcast](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_plugins_widget_definition.html#property-downcast) property of a CKeditor widget. We can register a custom method that will be used to *convert* a widget into its text-based representation. Also, it is called both when switching from **wysiwyg** mode to **source** mode and when calling `editor.getData()`.

Also, reading the docs, you get that:

> The downcast function will be executed in the CKEDITOR.plugins.widget context

meaning that `this` is pointing to your widget. So, essentially, I replaced all my widget's children by a single text node:

```
downcast: function(element) {
  element.children = [new CKEDITOR.htmlParser.text(CKEDITOR.tools.htmlEncode(this.data.text))];
  return element;
}
```

And it does the trick!